# JQuery: find and replace instances of HTML in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML in my page within a DIV.. There are multiple instances of it throughout the page, and its setting textbox (or other items)..

Id like to do a JQuery search and replace all occurrences of the HTML within a DIV (apexir_rollover_content) to change the item to a simple display.. There are multiple instances of the DIV..

Here is an html snippet..

```
<div id="apexir_rollover_content" style="height: 210px;">

<a href="javascript:void(false);">
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="2000" size="6" name="f05"></input>
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(false);">
    <input type="text" value="23162" maxlength="2000" size="6" name="f05"></input>
</a>
```

I want to change the line below so that it just has the value as standard text..

```
<input type="text" value="23162" maxlength="2000" size="6" name="f05"></input>
```

I can't do a global replace, as there will be other textbox items that I need to keep...

If someone could help, Id be grateful...

Thx

Comment: Can you clarify/explain this sentence : `Id like to do a JQuery search and replace all occurrences of the HTML within a DIV (apexir_rollover_content) to change the item to a simple display.` I don't understand what you want

Comment: How is this `input` different from the other `input`s on your page? Other than its value?

Comment: Hi George... Basically if the text box is inside a DIV as above, then I want to change the text item to a standard piece of text If its a textbox, or other control outside of the DIV, then I want the JQuery to leave it alone... The items inside the DIV have the wrong characteristics, and I cannot change them on the server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moreover, if You intend only replace as in the previous solution only some inputs the jquery statement can be filtered as in the following:

```
$("input[type='text']").filter('[name="f05"]').parent().html('<input type="text" value="23162" maxlength="2000" size="6" name="f05"></input>');
```

But if You intend to replace each anchor with the inner input so You could use:

```
        $('#apexir_rollover_content a').each(function() {
            var innerEle = $(this).children();
            $(this).replaceWith(innerEle);
        });
```

Comment: your help is much appreciated guys.. I will read the documentation... One final question.. How would I change (remove) the type i.e the HTML string from an input type to a standard piece of text for each item?

Comment: Simply, if you wish input translated into paragraphs (i.e.) so:
      `$('#apexir_rollover_content a').each(function() {
                var innerEle = $(this).children();
                var simpleParagraph = $('<p></p>').text(innerEle.val());
                $(this).replaceWith(simpleParagraph);
            }); 
     });`
bye

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would want to have a class or id to find the correct element. Since you do not have this, you can

1: use a jQuery selector to find the input element that needs to be replaced

```
jQuery("input[type='text']")
```

2: move one element above

```
.parent()
```

3: and replace the input field

```
.html('<input type="text" value="23162" maxlength="2000" size="6" name="f05"></input>')
```

I have created a jsFiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/sdhxybj1/

This is the JS jQuery code that you can use:

```
jQuery("input[type='text']").parent().html('<input type="text" value="23162" maxlength="2000" size="6" name="f05"></input>')
```

Comment: Hi Mumen. Thanks for this.. Probably a bit more information:  I need to only find the code if it is inside the DIV. There will be other text boxes on the page, and 2.. I need to then change the line so that its standard text.. (which can be clicked on with the event..) I run the jsFiddle.. (first time Ive seen or used this and its pretty neat..)  but nothing happens...

Comment: If you only need it when inside the div, you can change the jQuery selector to jQuery("div input[type='text']").

Comment: If you want to run the jsFiddle, you need to hit the "Run" button(;

Comment: @RichardLegge If you want to learn more about selectors, here is the documentation for it: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/